# Giving priority to first gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 gridviews on one page. I want to give priority to the first gridview. I have applied paging on both the gridviews. I want second gridview to appear after the last page of first gridview. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: you need to make second grid visible when last page index has been call.

Comment: and how do i refer to the last page index?

Comment: you need to sharpen your coding skills,gridview_pageindexchanging event will be your solution.